# apply lag on xts data from yahoo not working

Tags: r, lag

I am trying to apply lag on xts data but for some reason it does not want to work!

```
library(quantmod)
mystock <- c("GOOG")
getSymbols(mystock, src = "yahoo", from = "2020-01-01", to = "2021-01-01")
Google <- (GOOG)

Google <- subset(GOOG, select = GOOG.Adjusted)

googlets <- ts(Google)
head(googlets)

window5 <- data.frame(x5=Lag(googlets,5), x4=Lag(googlets,4), x3=Lag(googlets,3), 
                      x2=Lag(googlets,2), x1=Lag(googlets,1), googlets)
names(window5) <- c('x5','x4','x3', 'x2', 'x1', 'x')
window5
```

I am able to apply the lag on the data before conversion to ts. The results shows a non lagged number across every row.

can someone point me in a direction please

Comment: Please always provide `library` calls as stated in R tag info, this time I helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Using `cbind` works!

```
window5 <- cbind(x5=Lag(googlets,5), x4=Lag(googlets,4), x3=Lag(googlets,3), 
                 x2=Lag(googlets,2), x1=Lag(googlets,1), googlets)
colnames(window5) <- c('x5','x4','x3', 'x2', 'x1', 'x')
head(window5)
#           x5      x4      x3      x2      x1       x
# [1,] 1367.37      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA
# [2,] 1360.66 1367.37      NA      NA      NA      NA
# [3,] 1394.21 1360.66 1367.37      NA      NA      NA
# [4,] 1393.34 1394.21 1360.66 1367.37      NA      NA
# [5,] 1404.32 1393.34 1394.21 1360.66 1367.37      NA
# [6,] 1419.83 1404.32 1393.34 1394.21 1360.66 1367.37
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to take the Adjusted close, remove the times, perform a number of lags and convert to ts.  That could be done in one line using Ad which will select out the Adjusted column and a vector of lags which Lag supports with zoo objects.  Also note that we have reversed the non-standard order of columns used in the question but if you want that anyways use 5:0 in place of 0:5 .

```
ts(Lag(zoo(Ad(GOOG)), 0:5))
```

or via pipeline:

```
library(magrittr)
GOOG %>% Ad %>% zoo %>% Lag(0:5) %>% ts
```